# Overwrite linked list C

Tags: c, list, file

I'm writing a program which reads in a file and stores the information in a char* and a char**. When I add a node, it seems to overwrite what is already in my char** variable (sousCategorie), but it doesn't do that when I'm adding something from categorie. I don't know why it overwrite and the size of nouvelElement is always 2, whatever I add. Here's my code (I know that I use global variable but this is temporary):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct element element;
struct element
{
    int val;
    char* valeur;
    char** information;
    struct element *nxt;
};

typedef element* liste_s;


FILE* ouvrirFichier(char* nomFichier);
liste_s ajouterEnTete(liste_s liste, char** tableau);
void separerElements(char* ligne, char** info);
void afficherListe(liste_s l);

char* sousCategories[121];
char categorie[121];


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    liste_s ma_liste1 = NULL;
    FILE* fichier = NULL;
    char* elementSepares[121];
    char* info[121];


    fichier = ouvrirFichier(argv[1]);
    char tableau[121];
    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(tableau, 121, fichier))
    { 
          separerElements(tableau, info);
          ma_liste1 = ajouterEnTete(ma_liste1, info);
    }
    afficherListe(ma_liste1);

    return 0;
}


FILE* ouvrirFichier(char* nomFichier)
{
   FILE* fichier = NULL;
   fichier = fopen(nomFichier, "r");
   if (fichier == NULL) // Le fichier n'a pu être ouvert
   {
       perror("Erreur d'ouverture du fichier d'entrée ");
       exit(1);
   }
   return fichier;    
}




void separerElements(char* ligne, char** info) 
{
    char separateurs[] = "[]";
    char* element;
    int j = 0;
    for (element = strtok(ligne, separateurs); element; element = strtok(NULL, separateurs))
    {
         if (strcmp(element, " ") != 0 && strcmp(element, "\n") != 0)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                strcpy(categorie, element);
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                sousCategories[j] = element;
            }
        }
    }
}




liste_s ajouterEnTete(liste_s liste, char** tableau)
{
    int i = 0;
    element* nouvelElement = malloc(sizeof(element) + 1);
    nouvelElement -> information = malloc(sizeof(sousCategories) + 1); // This is probably here. Strdup() will do a seg fault

    nouvelElement->valeur = strdup(categorie);


    for(i = 0; i <= sizeof(sousCategories) / sizeof(sousCategories[i]); i++)
    {   
        nouvelElement -> information[i] = sousCategories[i];
    }

    nouvelElement->nxt = liste;

    return nouvelElement;
}

void afficherListe(liste_s liste)
{ 
    liste_s l = liste; 
    int i = 0;
    while (l != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", l->valeur);
        for(i = 0; i <= sizeof(l -> information) / sizeof(l -> information[0]); i++)
        {
            printf("-- %s\n", l -> information[i]);
        }
        l = l->nxt;
    } 
 }
```

The line nouvelElement -> information = malloc(sizeof(sousCategories) + 1); seems to be the problem, but everything I've tried doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: The code doesn't compile. You need to supply the definition of afficherListe().

Comment: You should manipulate `sousCategorie` in the same way you manipulate `categorie` : use strcpy, strdup, etc. If you're not easy with pointers, maybe the first thing to do is to declare `sousCategorie` as `char sousCategorie[121][121];`

Comment: I added it to my post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here it is :

```
void afficherListe(liste_s liste)
{
    liste_s l = liste; 
    int i = 0;
    while (l != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", l->valeur);
        for(i = 0; i <= sizeof(l -> information) / sizeof(l -> information[0]); i++)
        {
            printf("-- %s\n", l -> information[i]);
        }
        l = l->nxt;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add this in your question, not write it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `void separerElements(char* ligne, char** info)` seem to have a parameter that is not used, instead you copy to global variables.

Those global variables

```
char* sousCategories[121];
char categorie[121];
```

are not enough to handle what is returned by strtok since strtok internally uses a static buffer to parse a string, every time you call your separererElements the static buffer is overwritten.

categorie can only hold the last value you copy to it.

Instead do something like this

```
char* sousCategories[121];
char* categorie[121];
```

...

```
        if (j == 0)
        {
            categorie[j] = strdup(element);
        }
        else
        {
            sousCategories[j] = strdup(element);
        }
        ++j;
```

or better is to actually use the `char** info` argument you pass, but that is your call.